# Atribuir fórmula a uma célula em VBA - Aparece um @

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macro, fórmula

Estou aprendendo VBA e em uma sub onde tento atribuir o comando abaixo:

```
=PROCX([@[Empresa Emitente]];FORNECEDORES[Empresa Emitente];FORNECEDORES[DEPART];"";0;1)

Sub EXTRAIR_DEPART_UPDATE()

    Dim lastRowNoClear

    lastRowNoClear = Range("A16").End(xlDown).Row
    
    For i = 16 To lastRowNoClear
    
        Range("Q" & i).Select
        If Cells(i, 17) = "" Then
            Range("Q" & i).Value = "=PROCX([@[Empresa Emitente]],FORNECEDORES[Empresa Emitente],FORNECEDORES[DEPART],"""",0,1)"
        End If
        
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Dá o seguinte erro `#NOME?` e percebi que o VB coloca um `@` depois do sinal de `=`

Poderiam me dizer o que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Recomendação é não deixar tudo em caixa alta [link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Como corrigir uma #NAME?](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/como-corrigir-uma-name-erro-b6d54e31-a743-4d7d-9b61-40002a7b4286)

Na pergunta em específico, acredito que o erro esteja na declaração da fórmula dentro do VBA, pois ele não irá reconhecer o comando `PROCX` em pt-br.

Tente:

```
Range("Q" & i).Value = "=XLOOKUP([@[Empresa Emitente]],FORNECEDORES[Empresa Emitente],FORNECEDORES[DEPART],"""",0,1)"
```

Ao invés de:

```
Range("Q" & i).Value = "=PROCX([@[Empresa Emitente]],FORNECEDORES[Empresa Emitente],FORNECEDORES[DEPART],"""",0,1)"
```